# Rails mixins using ActiveSupport::Concern does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, mixins, activesupport

I have the following module/class defined in my `lib` folder

```
module Service::Log
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def logger
      Rails.logger
    end
  end
end


class Service::MyService
  include Service::Log
end
```

When I try to invoke `logger` method via an object instance I get an error message - NoMethodError: undefined method `logger' for - Service::MyService:0x007fdffa0f23a0

`Service::MyService.new.logger`

What am I doing wrong? I am using Rails `4.0.2`.

Answer (score 2):

You are defining the logger method as a class method, instead of a normal method. This should work:

```
module Service::Log
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def logger
    Rails.logger
  end
end

class Service::MyService
  include Service::Log
end

Service::MyService.new.logger
```

The way you were defining the method before allowed you to use the logger method on the class directly, such as:

```
Service::MyService.logger
```

Comment: Thanks yea that I can do without "extend ActiveSupport::Concern", why do I need  ActiveSupport::Concern ?

Comment: Just because it adds some sugar on top of Ruby modules: for example, it automatically includes the methods in the ClassMethods module in your class. Check http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html for more details

Comment: If you're curious about how Concern works, and problems it solves I've written up a detailed explanation here: http://monkeyandcrow.com/blog/reading_rails_concern/